# Unmarshal using JAXB starting with child element

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshal XML in the following format using JAXB:

```
<return_data api_call="getuser">
    <users>
       <user>
          <username>test_me</username>
          <account_expiration_date>0000-00-00</account_expiration_date>        
       </user>
    </users>
</return_data>
```

I would like to unmarshal the XML starting with the user element. However, when I try using '@XmlRootElement(name = "user")' I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse XML:
    at com.example.findAccount(AccountService.java:30)
    at com.example.main(AccountService.java:50)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"return_data"). Expected elements are <{}user>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at com.example.findAccount(AccountService.java:26)
    ... 1 more
```

Here is my Account model class:

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class Account {

    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

The service:

```
package com.example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import com.example.Account;

public class AccountService {

    public Optional<Account> findAccount(final String username) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://example.com/foo/bar" + username);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Account.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Account account = (Account) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(url);

            return Optional.ofNullable(account);
        } catch (JAXBException | MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse XML:", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test it //
        new AccountService().findAccount("user");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

JAXB unmarshalls complete XML, `@XmlRootElement(name = "user")` does not filter for "the first `user` element you see in the XML".

If you want this ("the first `user` element you see in the XML") there are a few options.

- The easiest is probably to unmarshal the complete XML and then just retrieve the `user` object from the resulting structure.
- Another option is to use StAX. Please see [this article by Blaise Doughan](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html) on how to do this.
- You could also pre-filter the XML you parse using SAX, but this will be probably not that easy.
- Finally, you could parse XML as DOM first, find the `user` node you need and unmarshal this node.

If you don't have much XML around the `user` element, I'd just parse the complete XML. Otherwise I'd opt to the StAX option. That would be something along the lines:

```
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("https://example.com/foo/bar" + username);
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
    xsr.nextTag();
    while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("user")) {
        xsr.nextTag();
    }

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Account.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<Account> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Account.class);
    xsr.close();

    Account user = jb.getValue();
```

(Copy-pasted from [this article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html) with a few adjustments, not tested at all.)

Kudos to [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan).